# SQL Server With clause recursive how works internally at the query level

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been using this query to identify, how with clause running the query in recursive.

```
CREATE Table #Temp1
(
    Deptno int, 
    ename Varchar(50),
    eno int
)

Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('John', 10, 1)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('Audrey', 10, 2)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('Jackson', 10, 3)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('Tommyy', 20, 4)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('Johniee', 20, 5)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('William', 20, 7)
Insert into #Temp1(ename, Deptno, eno) Values('Audreeee', 30, 6) 

with x (deptno, cnt, names, eno, len) as 
(
    select deptno, count(*) over (partition by deptno),
        cast(ename as varchar(100)),
        eno, 1
    from #Temp1

    union all

    select x.deptno, x.cnt,
        cast(x.names + ',' + e.ename as varchar(100)),
        e.eno, x.len+1
    from #Temp1 e, x
    where e.deptno = x.deptno and e.eno > x.eno
)
select 
    deptno, names, cnt, len, eno
from x 
where len = cnt
order by 1
```

Result set

```
10  John    3   1   1
10  Audrey  3   1   2
10  Jackson 3   1   3
20  Tommyy  3   1   4
20  Johniee 3   1   5
20  William 3   1   7
30  Audreeee    1   1   6
20  Johniee,William 3   2   7
20  Tommyy,Johniee  3   2   5
20  Tommyy,William  3   2   7
20  Tommyy,Johniee,William  3   3   7
10  Audrey,Jackson  3   2   3
10  John,Audrey 3   2   2
10  John,Jackson    3   2   3
10  John,Audrey,Jackson 3   3   3
```

With clause recursive query:

From the above query am completely confusing about the how the concatenation happening in that query.

Assume Top 7 rows are the result set of the anchor query. I need to know from that result how does the second query process the result set.

Particularly with the deptno: 10,20

Detail explanation required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listing is a result of this line:

```
cast(x.names + ',' + e.ename as varchar(100)),
```

Your recursive portion executes as many times as there are people in a department with a lower `eno` than someone else in the same department.

So for department `10`, first you get each person by themselves from the top portion of your query (anchor) as you suggested.

Then you get `John,Audrey`, `John,Jackson`, and `Audrey,Jackson` because you're adding the `ename` with the higher `eno` to the one with a lower `eno`.  You get one more iteration that gets you all three names since they all have a different `eno` value.

Perhaps a different example will be helpful:

The following outputs numbers from 1-5, the anchor executes once, then the recursive portion executes until there are no more records that satisfy the criteria:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT 1 AS num
              UNION  ALL
              SELECT num + 1
              FROM cte
              WHERE num < 5
              )
SELECT * 
FROM  cte
```